# Как правильно вывести информацию в OpenCart при заказе?

Tags: php, sql, opencart

Ситуация такая, вот код, который создаем в папке Orders файлы с расширение .sal, где выносится информация о заказе. Адрес, телефон, имя, и т.к. Нужно еще добавить, чтобы правильно отображались заказы, а именно цены опций и их points (опций).

Как правильно вытянуть информацию?

```
    $result_for_sal = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_product WHERE order_id = (SELECT order_id FROM oc_order_product ORDER BY order_product_id DESC LIMIT 1)");

    $fileName =  $result_for_sal->row['order_id'].".sal";

    $id = $result_for_sal->row['order_id'];

    $result_for_base_sm = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE order_id = '$id'");

    $firstname =  $result_for_base_sm->row["payment_firstname"].' '.$result_for_base_sm->row["payment_lastname"];

    $telephone = $result_for_base_sm->row["telephone"];
    $country  = $result_for_base_sm->row["payment_country"];
    $region  = $result_for_base_sm->row["payment_zone"];
    $city  = $result_for_base_sm->row["payment_city"];
    $address  = $result_for_base_sm->row["payment_address_1"];
    $email =  $result_for_base_sm->row["email"];
    $comment =  $result_for_base_sm->row["comment"];
    $sale_for = $result_for_base_sm->row["payment_method"];
    $sale_for = strip_tags($sale_for);

$str = <<<EOD
[Client] 
Name= $firstname
MPhone= $telephone
CPhone=
ZIP=
Country= $country 
Region= $region
City= $city
Address= $address
EMail= $email

[Options]
SaleType=1
Comment= $comment
OrderNumber= $id
DeliveryCondition= $sale_for
ReserveDate= 
EOD;
        for($i = 0; $i<count($result_for_sal->rows); $i++) {
            $points = $result_for_sal->rows[$i]['points'];
            $price = $result_for_sal->rows[$i]['price'];
            $counts = $result_for_sal->rows[$i]['quantity'];
$str .= <<<EOD
\n[$i]
GoodID=$points
Price=$price
Count=$counts
EOD;
        }
        $str = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1251", $str);
        file_put_contents('Orders/'.$fileName,$str);
```

Price - цена опции
Points - уникальный ID (дополнительный для опции) :

```
$points = $result_for_sal->rows[$i]['points'];
$price = $result_for_sal->rows[$i]['price'];
```

[image]

С SQL запросами у меня не очень, кто может правильно направить, куда рыть? Чтобы правильно вывести?

Каждое наименование должно в итоге выходить так:

```
[0]
GoodID=020 (Points - уникальный ID опции)
Price=15.2000 (Price - цена опции)
Count=1 (Quantity - количество, сейчас выводит правильно)
[1]
GoodID=0220
Price=15.2000
Count=1
[2]
GoodID=0212
Price=15.2000
Count=1
[3]
GoodID=0233
Price=15.2000
Count=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вам нужно изменить sql запрос в $result_for_sale на:

```
$sql = "SELECT op . * , oo.price, oo.points
        FROM  `oc_order_product` AS op
        LEFT JOIN  `oc_order_option` AS oo ON oo.order_id = op.order_id
        AND oo.order_product_id = op.order_product_id
        ORDER BY  `order_id` DESC ,  `product_id` DESC ";

$result_for_sale = $this->db->query($sql);
```